# Can't import NSWorkspace from AppKit in Python

Tags: python

I have installed appkit in my venv but I can't seem to import any of the packages within it. I can import "AppKit" but that's it. Please help..

Comment: I had the exact same problem. The answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53808723/importerror-no-module-named-appkit-after-installing-appkit-and-pyobjc