# No module named Appkit. If I try to install it in pycharm it keeps saying "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:"

Tags: python, text-to-speech, appkit, google-text-to-speech

I'm using pycharm for this and I can't seem to figure out how to fix this error.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/syedrishad/PycharmProjects/OpenCVPython/venv/Text To Speech.py", line 44, in Text_to_speech
    playsound('DataFlair.mp3')
  File "/Users/syedrishad/OpenCVPython/lib/python3.8/site-packages/playsound.py", line 55, in _playsoundOSX
    from AppKit     import NSSound
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'AppKit'
```

Here's the code:

```
## import libraries

from tkinter import *
from gtts import gTTS
from playsound import playsound



################### Initialized window####################

root = Tk()
root.geometry('350x300')
root.resizable(0,0)
root.config(bg = 'ghost white')
root.title('DataFlair - TEXT_TO_SPEECH')


##heading
Label(root, text = 'TEXT_TO_SPEECH' , font='arial 20 bold' , bg ='white smoke').pack()
Label(root, text ='DataFlair' , font ='arial 15 bold', bg = 'white smoke').pack(side = BOTTOM)




#label
Label(root, text ='Enter Text', font ='arial 15 bold', bg ='white smoke').place(x=20,y=60)


##text variable
Msg = StringVar()


#Entry
entry_field = Entry(root,textvariable =Msg, width ='50')
entry_field.place(x=20 , y=100)


###################define function##############################

def Text_to_speech():
    Message = entry_field.get()
    speech = gTTS(text = Message)
    speech.save('DataFlair.mp3')
    playsound('DataFlair.mp3')

def Exit():
    root.destroy()

def Reset():
    Msg.set("")

#Button
Button(root, text = "PLAY" , font = 'arial 15 bold', command = Text_to_speech, width =4).place(x=25, y=140)
Button(root,text = 'EXIT',font = 'arial 15 bold' , command = Exit, bg = 'OrangeRed1').place(x=100,y=140)
Button(root, text = 'RESET', font='arial 15 bold', command = Reset).place(x=175 , y =140)


#infinite loop to run program
root.mainloop()
```

I'm very confused about this and other people's solutions do not work for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been trying to fix this for a week now. Oh, and this is not my code. I'm taking a tutorial and this was one of the projects I've been working on.

Comment: pip uninstall AppKit # there is another package in this name, creating conflict then:

pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall PyObjC PyObjC-core

from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53808723/importerror-no-module-named-appkit-after-installing-appkit-and-pyobjc

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You don't have `AppKit` installed. That's why interpreter is complaining about it.

You have to install the package, there's two possibilities:

1. In terminal type
   `pip install AppKit`
2. In PyCharm do:
   Preferences -> Project Interpreter -> click "+" -> type `AppKit` -> Install Package

Et voila, it should be working now.

Comment: Yes, but that's the problem. If I try to install to install it using the first method, it gives me a huge error. If I use the second method it says ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Comment: Did you try following this page? http://nitipit.github.io/appkit/